# php mysql select 4 weeks from month

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select all 4 weeks from the month. There is how I get the week days:

`SELECT impression_ip, WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(impression_time)) FROM impressions WHERE impression_time BETWEEN start_timestamp AND end_timestamp`

idk the mysql function but it should be something like MONTHWEEK if u get me

[PHP fragment here](http://jsfiddle.net/z3ahP/)

Comment: What exact semantics do you want for MONTHWEEK?  In particular, how would you handle, e.g., February 2012, spanning three full weeks and two partial weeks, or September 2012, spanning four full weeks and two partial?

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be implemented prior to executing the SQL statement.

Given today's date - `2012-05-09`

```
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");// Take the current date
//Add four weeks
$plusFourWeeks = strtotime($currentDate . " +4 weeks ");

echo $plusFourWeeks;
```

Date After adding four weeks: `2012-06-06`

```
                            For your convenience -
                          or if you just don't trust me ;)
```

Comment: You want to `SELECT` a bunch of rows from your database that fall over the period of four weeks.  Correct?

Comment: [I'd prefer not to edit your PHP code in jsfiddle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/172936).  If you have more relevant code you should put it in your main post.